# Showing an additional modeless window with C++ and WinApi

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a class called GUIMain which registers, creates, and shows a main window for my program. On it is a button which, when the user clicks it, displays an additional window.

If I was writing this in C#, I would have two options:

```
AdditionalForm myForm = new AdditionalForm();
myForm.ShowDialog(this); // blocking. Returns when myForm is closed;
someOtherFunction();
```

or

```
AdditionalForm myForm = new AdditionalForm();
myForm.Show(this);   // non-blocking.
someOtherFunction(); // runs while myForm is still visible
```

or, heck, even this would work:

```
AdditionalForm myForm = new AdditionalForm();
new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
  {
    myForm.ShowDialog(this);   // blocks in a separate thread
  })).Start();
someOtherFunction(); // runs while myForm is still visible
```

But I'm writing this in C++, not C#.

I have an additional class called PreviewWindow which has the public member functions `Register()`, `Create()`, and `Show()`. The last function contains a message loop which basically makes it a blocking call - analogous to C#'s `ShowDialog()`.

How can I  either re-write `PreviewWindow::Show()` so that it doesn't have a blocking loop:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Or alternatively, how can I call it on a separate thread?

I've currently got:

```
previewWindow = new PreviewWindow(hInstance, hWnd);

previewWindow->Register();
previewWindow->Create();
previewWindow->Show();         // blocks :(
previewWindow->DisplayImage(); // never runs.
```

I have tried `CreateThread` but it's not liking that the 3rd argument is a member function. I've tried making it a *static* member function but it doesn't seem to like that either. It's saying DWORD (__stdcall *)() isn't compatible with LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have only one event loop, it will handle all windows except modal ones (which run their own message loop to block the UI). Then your `PreviewWindow::Show` is just `ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW);`. Multi-threading should generally be saved for when it's absolutely necessary.